# How to configure web config for hosting AJAX enabled WCF over HTTP for web application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, web-services, httpwebrequest

I've made simple AJAX enabled WCF which runs on localhost, but when I tried it to over HTTP, WCF is not running. How do I configure web config for it to host over HTTP? My web config which created automatically adding WCF and running on localhost:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ASPXCommerceWCFServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="ASPXCommerceWCFService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ASPXCommerceWCFServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ASPXCommerceWCFService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is your client running on localhost with the service on a different machine?  You can't do cross-domain calls like that.

Comment: yeah i know but dnt know how to configure please provide sample code of config

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to make a cross-domain call, which modern browsers block.   There appear to be some work-arounds:

[Cross-site ajax call to a WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555595/cross-site-ajax-call-to-a-wcf-service)

[JSONP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834511.aspx)

[Cross-Domain AJAX Enabled WCF Service](http://blog.csdn.net/teddyma/article/details/5353076)

Comment: calling cross domain  ive thought about later.. but right now i need to know hosting it on over htttp...

Comment: You said it runs on localhost, right? I assume you're using something like `http://localhost` - that's running over HTTP. If your client app is on your local machine, and you're hosting the service on *another* machine - like `http://somemachine/`, you will have to deal with cross domain calls.

Comment: yeah i get it...but i think you are not getting my problems..ive domain www.domain.com and ive to host svc with in this domain only sothat function may call this service and run..right now m not able to recive that service ?